# Run an SQL script to a certain Database or Table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database

How do I run an SQL script to a certain Database or Table in C#?
This is my current setup:
    I have a server with multiple databases inside. I want to run an SQL script on a certain Database or Table, How do I run the script in C# wherein I could define in which database/table the script should run? Thanks

Comment: What you are using to connect to the database? ORM? ADO.NET?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Comment: @dksandimas wants to know if you connect to the Server from C# through the System.Data Namespace classes (ADO.Net) or if you use an OR Mapper like Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `USE` statement. That is, try using the database name before running the sql script something like,

```
USE DatabaseName;
SELECT * FROM TableName;
```

Otherwise you could also try associating the database name in the tablename like,

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseName.TableName;
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Just one of many ways, not the cleanest: When you create your SqlCommand set the ConnectionString directly in its constructor.

[SqlCommand Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

[SqlConnection Class (your ConnectionString)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My connection string is direct to the server (root) since my program needs to list all the databases inside the server and perform script to one of the databases inside it

Comment: Well, that completely another question: in the master database on every SQL Server there is a table sysObjects. You can query that to find all meta-informations about your Schema in other DBs on the Server.

Comment: so you mean, I have to generate a connection string for each database?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can also change the DataBase Property in the SqlConnection Object. But yes, you Need to provide the correct SqlConnection every time you create a SqlCommand object.

Answer (score 0):

To run script from C# you should right the script like this. Here you are defining the database name as 'Initial Catalog'.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class ExcuteScript : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string sqlConnectionString = @"Initial Catalog=northwind;Data Source=subhash\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;";

    string script = File.ReadAllText(@"E:\Project Docs\TACT\northwinddata.sql");

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

    Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));

    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
    }
}
```

After that your sql script file should manage the requirements.like which table you need to use in your query and you can also connect the tables of other databases using '.' operator syntax is like this.

```
 select * from [database].[schema].[table]  where <condition>
```